# C++ : initialize input programmatically

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

If we have this code snippet:

```
int a;
cout << "please enter a value: "; 
cin >> a;
```

And in the terminal, the input request would look like this

```
please enter a value: _
```

How can I programatically simulate a user's typing in it.

Comment: Search for input/output redirection. Many shells support a syntax like `program < foo` to read input from a file called "foo".

Comment: Send it a character followed by a newline?

Comment: How about using a generic [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) reference, and use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) when "simulating" and `std::cin` when not?

Comment: Can you tell me if it's possible to use readline library for simulating?

Comment: @KiraSan What is _readline library_? Do you have a link? IMHO Joachim's proposal is the best idea, if you want to have all inside your program's code, and test e.g. with a decent unit test framework. Otherwise just stick to input redirection from shell.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Here is a wikipedia article on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline

Comment: @KiraSan Doesn't look like this would help to solve your problem. May be you should clarify more, why and how the existing proposals here don't help to solve your problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Could you give me a simple example on how to perform I/O redirection ?

Comment: @KiraSan It's already given in the answer below.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Oh well, I don't prefer using files for my program. How to use `std::istream` to replace `std::cin` in my case?

Comment: @KiraSan Have a look at my answer, to see various _inside code_ options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a sample how to manipulate `cin`'s input buffer using the **[`rdbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf)** function, to retrieve fake input from a `std::istringstream`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    istringstream iss("1 a 1 b 4 a 4 b 9");
    cin.rdbuf(iss.rdbuf());  // This line actually sets cin's input buffer
                             // to the same one as used in iss (namely the
                             // string data that was used to initialize it)
    int num = 0;
    char c;
    while(cin >> num >> c || !cin.eof()) {
        if(cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            string dummy;
            cin >> dummy;
            continue;
        }
        cout << num << ", " << c << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**[See it working](http://ideone.com/b3M9Tb)**

---

Another option (closer to what Joachim Pileborg said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656187/c-initialize-input-programmatically?noredirect=1#comment43728404_27656187) IMHO), is to put your reading code into a separate function e.g.

```
int readIntFromStream(std::istream& input) {
    int result = 0;
    input >> result;
    return result;
}
```

This enables you to have different calls for testing and production, like

```
// Testing code
std::istringstream iss("42");
int value = readIntFromStream(iss);

// Production code
int value = readIntFromStream(std::cin);
```

Comment: Can we pass that fake input to the user so that he can modify it?

Comment: A good analogy to what I'm trying to get is a web login information in Google Chrome, when you enter to a login page and your username is stored in Chrome, it will directly initialize the input field with that username giving you the possibility to edit it. hope that this clarify my point.

Comment: Yes! a shell history is a good analogy as well. That's why I asked if anyone has an example on how to use readline and initialize it with a chosen value before giving control to the user.

Comment: @KiraSan In short no, that's not possible in this way. That's a completely different question. Looks you're asking for a XY-problem. Would you like to create something similar like a _shell history_? Then you can't just do this by intercepting `cin`, in this case the _readline library_ you've mentioned seems to be more appropriate to achieve what you want. I think some lib like [ncurses](http://ndk-xx.sourceforge.net/) would also be appropriate to implement such features.

Comment: BTW I don't like using ncurses for my program, since it would take full control of all the terminal's screen.

Comment: @KiraSan _"since it would take full control of all the terminal's screen"_ That's what you'll finally need to achieve, to implement such. So what?

Comment: `readline` seems more comfortable for my program, only if I could initialize it. Thank you for your support :)

Comment: I've already written most of the program, if I go for ncurses then I've to rewrite everything.

Comment: @KiraSan So you should ask another question, where you're particularly stuck with the _readline library_ (a better one as the last one you tried please. That one received down and close votes quickly, because you've been very unclear, didn't show a code sample and where you're stuck in particular!).

Answer (score 2):

Hey why don't you write your input in a plain text file and redirect it to cin ???
It's the simplest method.

Open Command Prompt.
Suppose your text file which will used as input is `in.txt` and your program is `prog.exe`.
Keep the text file and the program in same folder. `cd` to your folder. Then type:

`prog.exe < in.txt`

Remember, your text file will be treated exactly as it is. Shoudld't be a problem if you know `cin` only catches upto next whitespace character, while string input functions (e.g. `cin.getline`) only catch upto next newline character.

```
//Sample prog.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    do
    {
        cin >> num;
        cout << (num + 1) << endl;
    }
    while (num != 0);

    return 0;
}

//Sample in.txt
2
51
77
0

//Sample output
3
52
78
1
```

Sorry if you are on other platform, I don't know about them.

Comment: The platform is clearly specified with the [tag:linux] tag. Though it would be the same syntax for file redirection an a linux shell.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'm new to all this.