# How to simulate user input in c++?

Tags: c++, cin

Suppose I have some file Foo.txt. It represents user input:

```
10 A Foo 
9  G Foo2
24 B Foo3
```

My program works with user input like that:

```
int main(void)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
   {
       int a;    cin >> a;
       char c;   cin >> c;
       string s; cin >> s;   
       // Some stuff, which works with input values
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Is there way to simulate such user input? (I want to redirect Foo.txt to input). 
I just don't want input such values every time during for example debugging of my program

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656187/c-initialize-input-programmatically

Comment: You can simply use a stringstream instead of `cin`